# Find duplicate value in the below data frame for each cell

Tags: python, dataframe

[image]

```
0   1   2
0   BR1 C1  C1
1   C1  R3  None
2   PCB1    None    None
3   Q1  R3  U1
4   R2  None    None
5   R3  None    None
6   U1  None    None
```

Here C1 is repeated in rows and columns
R3 is also the same.
How to go through each cell and find duplicate values an entire data frame

Comment: You can do a set of the data in the dataframe. Then check against that set

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For your next question, you are expected to research and get started.  Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the dataframe and use value_counts() like this:

```py
stack = df.stack().value_counts()
stack[stack>1]
```